# How to connect to public WiFi

Tags: wifi

In hotels or at airports, connection to the public WiFi requires you to start a browser session, which is then redirected to some log-in page. Due to security concerns, browsers now pop up warnings about such redirection, and if you're on a company laptop, you may not be able to proceed. Also, any HTTPS site won't allow redirect in the first place, and more and more websites start implementing HTTPS.

Is there a reliable way to get to the login page for a public WiFi network that doesn't require hoping you know a site that's still on HTTP, or even better, that won't be blocked by overzealous company security?

Comment: Browsers often have some built-in http url that they try to load to see if they get redirected to a login page.  Firefox has http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt

Comment: Much of this seems like it's something you have to take up with your company's IT department.

Comment: I'd go in the other direction and *not use it*. Such kind of Wifi is a great way to get the computer taken over by someone. The warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Take a HTTP-only site and bookmark it?

Comment: This isn't a travel question. How many corporate laptops are set up is there's a VPN client that automatically connects and always tunnels 100% of traffic back to the company. New clients detect captive portals and handle appropriately. Old or misconfigured clients don't, in which the answer is too bad, its working as designed.

Comment: Windows 10, Android, iOS, macOS and Linux will all detect this automatically. Unfortunately Windows starts the default browser to log in to the captive portal, while all the others have a special restricted browser. Consider not using Windows.

Comment: @user71659: I disagree - connecting to such networks is something you encounter a lot more when you travel, not unlike strange toilets.

Comment: That "***overzealous*** company security" Is doing exactly what it ought to. If you disagree, talk to your company IT and (try to) get it changed.

Comment: If you can not, or do not want to, connect with your laptop, can you bring a separate devise to connect? Like an older phone which you now only use for that task? One not connected to your laptop?

Comment: @Willeke: I do need to get online to connect to the company VPN to work. And indeed, IT is trying to do good and keep us safe; but also making it challenging to work.

Comment: @Jonas, the company might prefer to pay for roaming rather than for you to connect to wifi networks they would not trust. A company computer is often worth enough to pay to avoid the risks.

Comment: @Willeke: They don't, actually, as the two budgets are with separate entities. It's more a case of one hand of IT not knowing what the other hand of IT does.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. **Your device may support this automatically** - Particularly for Android, but probably also for several other systems, you may see a notification to "sign into the network" or similar.  Click or tap it, and your device will open a web browser.  Surprisingly, this even works with some non-web devices such as the Nintendo Switch (which does not have a "regular" web browser at all).
2. **If not, use a non-HTTPS website**, such as http://www.example.com or http://neverssl.com/.  example.com is particularly safe for this purpose because it is owned and operated by IANA and its domain is permanently reserved for use in software documentation.  Chrome will also send requests to http://google.com/generate_204 over HTTP notwithstanding the use of HSTS (note that if your internet is working correctly, that URL will not cause a page to load, because Google responds with HTTP 204 No Content).

Finally, as some people have mentioned in the comments, you should be careful about trusting open networks.  Once you have signed in, don't do anything sensitive unless the entire site uses HTTPS.  People can steal your session cookies even if your username and password were encrypted, so just having HTTPS on the login page is inadequate.

Comment: And just accessing the login mask, even if legitimate, is enough to secretly get malware. It's not only about security/privacy of data from visited websites.

Comment: @deviantfan: If you know of a way to forcibly download *and install* malware without the user's consent, please report it to the developers of the browser(s) concerned.  It is a security bug and must be seriously investigated.

Comment: @Kevin It's easy enough if they've got Office installed and are running Windows 10...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no. A drive by infection that worked against any win10 machine with Office installed would be **big** headlines.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not even talking about the browser (only). And I'm also not talking about one specific bug, but there are plenty of known (already fixed) ones, and there will be more in future (that can be used before they get fixed) ... Other than that, many people don't update often enough. etc.etc.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. I use always cnn.com as they are still http, but this is better.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks - the question was prompted by my go-to site going https. Good to know that www.example.com will stick around.

Comment: @vidarlo It's not quite drive-by, but it's up there. One malicious OneNote file and you've got System-level privileges from an unelevated user; it doesn't even need to exploit any bugs. For obvious reasons I'm not going to go into it in great detail, but Microsoft are aware of it and have done nothing about it for at least four months. I expect that it wouldn't be too difficult to exploit a bug in Edge (which has the power to single-handedly trigger a BSOD when playing a malicious video file) to launch the attack without the need for Office, but I don't care enough to try to discover one r/n.

Comment: Oh, please do publish how edge can cause an bsod...

Comment: x.com is less typing

Comment: Please, don't spread FUD in the comments section.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it's only FUD if it's untrue.

Comment: I don't think it's that surprising that a console designed to be portable, and therefore used when travelling, works with the kind of WiFi networks you commonly encounter while travelling.

Comment: example.com is not the safest - as you say it's purpose is for software documentation. There is no requirement that an HTTP website is available at that domain.

Comment: @OrangeDog: "Safe" in the sense that it will not expire and be bought by a pornographic website.  Most other domains do not have this property.

Comment: @Kevin you're thinking of x-ample.com ;)

Comment: http://msftconnecttest.com/redirect is the microsoft link - will redirect to msn when you're connected to the internet, otherwise will redirect to the login page